# New instance of class created or just space in memory allocated?

Tags: java, instance

**UPDATE**

```
public Fish mate(Fish other){
  if (this.health > 0 && other.health > 0 && this.closeEnough(other)){

    int babySize = (((this.size + other.size) /2));
    int babyHealth = (((this.health + other.health) /2));
    double babyX = (((this.x + other.x) /2.0));
    double babyY = (((this.y + other.y) /2.0));

    new Fish (babySize, babyHealth, babyX, babyY);
  }
  return null;
}
```

When `new Fish` is called, is there a new instance of `Fish` floating around somewhere without a **reference** or have I just allocated memory for a new `Fish` without actually instantiating it?

**Can I get the `new Fish` call to create an actual instance of the `Fish` with a unique reference name other than iterating through a loop?**

Comment: The last part isn't clear

Comment: I think there is a `Fish` created, but since it is unreachable it is available for garbage collection and will cease to exist at any moment (when the JVM decides to destroy it).

Comment: @Gendarme how do I get it to have unique names each time mate is called?

Comment: @ZacTaylor What you have done is completely useless. That's my point. Your Fish is *unreachable*. I think what you want to do is `return new Fish(babySize, babyHealth, babyX, babyY);`.

Comment: You most likely want to keep your fish population in a collection (not a "unique variable name").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When new `Fish` is called, is there a new instance of Fish floating around somewhere without a variable name or have I just allocated memory for a new `Fish` without actually instantiating it?

A new `Fish` object will be created, and will be garbage-collected since there is no reference to it. 
The garbage collection will take place *(sometime)* after the constructor of `Fish` is done.
In your case that doesn't make much sense, but sometimes it does, if instantiating an object will start a new `Thread` or run some other routines that you want to be run *only once*.

> If I have only allocated memory or there is a `Fish` without a name, how can I get the new `Fish` call to create an actual instance of the `Fish` with a unique variable name?

This is not very clear. But I sense that you just want to `return new Fish(...);` and assign it to a variable yourself where you call it, something like:

```
Fish babyFish = femaleFish.mate(maleFish);
```

Comment: Your answer suggests that garbage collection would take place right after the constructor work had finished which isn't always the case (and in fact it rarely is).

Comment: @mewa I added a little clarification of this. Thanks

Comment: I don't care about returning the new Fish I just want the mate method to create a new Fish with a unique name each time mate is used regardless of the which Fish object called it. Is that possible?

Comment: The name is not up to your method, it is up to the **caller** of the method. I think you are going about this the wrong way... Maybe you should try to explain exactly what is your end-game goal here and there might/probably be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: @ZacTaylor What do you mean by "unique name"? The constructor doesn't take any name parameter as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Gendarme The name of the variable that references the Fish

Comment: @Idos I'm trying to avoid something like: Fish babyFish = new Fish(babySize, babyHealth, babyX, babyY); Because then each time mate is called the new Fish will be referenced by the name babyFish ideally I would have a unique name for the new Fish each time mate is called.

Comment: @ZacTaylor In that case you probably want to have a global array somewhere and insert it into the array. Right now your Fish is *unreachable*, meaning that you can assume it doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Gendarme I updated the second half of the question... is the only to do it with an array. You mentioned `return new Fish(babySize, babyHealth, babyX, babyY);` what would reutnring the object do in terms of how its refenced?

Comment: @ZacTaylor You can't. But if you `return new Fish(...)`, you can do something like this: `Fish kid = motherFish.mate(fatherFish);`.

Answer (score 4):

> "*have I just allocated memory for a new Fish without actually instantiating it?*"

No. The instance is initialized (the constructor is executed), but if no reference is kept for this instance it will eventually be garbage collected. Keep in mind that a reference can be kept even if your code doesn't do so, for example if the constructor puts `this` in some static variable.

Comment: Is there anyway to give to new Fish a unique name or can I only do something like:
    Fish babyFish = new Fish(babySize, babyHealth, babyX, babyY);

Comment: @ZacTaylor as I commented on the question itself, that's not clear at all. What do you mean by "unique name" (or just "name" really)?

Comment: the name of the variable that references the Fish

Comment: First, only ask one question at a time (read [ask]). Second this makes no sense, but if we were to suppose it did, what's your next step? Suppose you found a way to have "unique variable name" (identifier...). You obviously don't know what that "name" is, what would you do with it?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know I could only ask one question. As for the unique reference (I confused variable name and object reference) I wanted to be able to set the reference like Gendarme talked about in the comments of Idos' answer. I didn't know returning new Fish would do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following figure's explanation really helped me when I had confusion in the beginning and I hope will help you as well.You can think of Employee as Fish here.

[image]

In your case you created a `new Fish()` object locally inside a method, so the lifetime of that should be assigned locally as well.The garbage collector always looks for unused objects and will identify this suitable for collection as soon as your method exits,along with other locals defined inside the method.

You are returning null, so this method can not be treated as factory method structure since it does not return an instance.I am not sure what you mean by :

> Can I get the new Fish call to create an actual instance of the Fish with a unique reference name other than iterating through a loop?

But I think you asked if you can use the exact `new Fish()` that is inside the method.The short answer is: no. Although you can definitely create another `new Fish()` but you need a reference variable to retrieve that address or you can return the instance for the method instead of null,which will be a static factory method and is known as a good practice when you want to separately name your constructors.

In a more specific manner to answer both of your updated questions:

1)You did created a new object when you wrote `new Fish()` but you did not create a reference variable to really retrieve that object information.It's like you have built a house but you don't know the address of the house.Then you can never get to the house. What will happen is because of the lack of retrieval process, this object will be identified as unused by the garbage collector and hence it will be collected.

2)Since there is no reference/pointer or anything to get the information stored in the new object, you cannot retrieve the exact `new Fish()` inside the method but you can certainly create another object with a reference variable if you really wish to retrieve the information stored in the object.

Lastly, although it is mainly written for C language usage, the following document by Nick Parlante of Stanford University does an exceptional job in explaining references, stack,and heap memories.[Click here.](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

First, let me clear up some confusion in your terminology: An *object* doesn't have a name. A *variable* has a name, but you can have many variables of different names all referring to the same object. Having a named variable reference the object does not mean the object has a name.

If you do `new Fish()` but don't assign the new reference to anything, the new object will be *unreachable* as soon as the constructor returns.

There is no way to recover that reference, and the object will be unallocated by the next Garbage Collection run.